# Поля ввода Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<h4 v-if="!showInput" class="card-title" @click="showInput = true" {{dataObject.attributes['name']}}</h4>

<input v-else type="text" v-model="title" v-on:keyup.enter="event => editField(event, 'name'),showInput = false ">


<h4 v-if="!showInput" class="card-title" @click="showInput = true" {{dataObject.attributes['surname']}}</h4>

<input v-else type="text" v-model="title" v-on:keyup.enter="event => editField(event, 'surname'),showInput = false ">


<h4 v-if="!showInput" class="card-title" @click="showInput = true" {{dataObject.attributes['age']}}</h4>

<input v-else type="text" v-model="title" v-on:keyup.enter="event => editField(event, 'age'),showInput = false ">
```

Есть поля вода порядка 10 шт, при клике по h4 он скрывается и появляется input, который по нажатию enter улетает в функцию и там обрабатывается.

Сейчас при клике по h4 открываются все формы, как решить чтоб каждый редактировался индивидуально ?

```
    editField(event, key) {
        const value = event.target.innerText;
        if(value !== this.dataObject.attributes[key]){
            this.dataObject.attributes[key] = value;
            axios.post(this.postURL, {user_id: this.dataObject.id, field_name: key, field_value: value})
        }
    },
```

Comment: Я не знаток ВуеЖС, но у вас не видно привязки конкретного `h4` к конкретному `input`. Если `showInput` кастомный атрибут, то его можно попробовать сделать разным для всех инпутов: `showNameInput`, `showSurnameInput` и т.д.

Это все догадки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, нужно стараться использовать компонентный подход `vue`. Я бы сделал компонент, который заведовал бы логикой и данными для решения вашей задачи.

Это ни в коем случае не эталон, но как наглядный пример сойдет, а именно показывает как компонент "разгружает" родительский компонент (здесь приложение) и берет на себя всю работу по решению вашей задачи, т.е. взял данные из родителя и уже сам решает когда ему что показать (конечно в зависимости от действий пользователя): поле ввода `<input>` или текст `<h4>`, а в родитель отдает уже готовые данные для синхронизации.

```js
Vue.component('inputForm', {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      keyInputForm: null,
      thisValue: this.value
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4 v-if="!keyInputForm" class="card-title" @click="keyInputForm = true">{{ value }}</h4>
      <input v-else type="text" :value="value" v-model="thisValue" @input="$emit('input', thisValue)" @blur="keyInputForm = false">
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dataObject: {
      name: 'Name',
      surname: 'Surname',
      age: '17'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input-form v-model="dataObject[key]" :key="key"></input-form>
  <hr> Это объект dataObject
  <pre>
    {{ dataObject }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Здесь без `v-for`

```js
Vue.component('inputForm', {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      keyInputForm: null,
      thisValue: this.value
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4 v-if="!keyInputForm" class="card-title" @click="keyInputForm = true">{{ value }}</h4>
      <input v-else type="text" :value="value" v-model="thisValue" @input="$emit('input', thisValue)" @blur="keyInputForm = false">
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dataObject: {
      name: 'Name',
      surname: 'Surname',
      age: '17'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input-form v-model="dataObject.name"></input-form>
  <input-form v-model="dataObject.surname"></input-form>
</div>
```

с функцией, добавленной в компонент

```js
Vue.component('inputForm', {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      keyInputForm: null,
      thisValue: this.value
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4 v-if="!keyInputForm" class="card-title" @click="keyInputForm = true">{{ value }}</h4>
      <input v-else type="text" :value="value" :name="name" v-model="thisValue" @input="$emit('input', thisValue)" @blur="keyInputForm = false;$emit('edit-field', $event)">
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dataObject: {
      name: 'Name',
      surname: 'Surname',
      age: '17',
      id: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editField(e) {
      console.clear();
      const value = e.target.value;
      const key = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name');
      // axios.post(this.postURL, { user_id: this.dataObject.id, field_name: key, field_value: value })
      console.log('axios post => ', {
        user_id: this.dataObject.id,
        field_name: key,
        field_value: value
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input-form v-model="dataObject.name" name="name" @edit-field="editField"></input-form>
  <input-form v-model="dataObject.surname" name="surname" @edit-field="editField"></input-form>
</div>
```

и на случай, когда нет свойства на которое ссылается `v-model`, допустим:

```
    dataObject: {
      name: 'Name',
      // surname: 'Surname',
      age: '17',
      id: 1
    }
```

наглядный пример:

```js
Vue.component('inputForm', {
  props: ['value', 'name'],
  data() {
    return {
      keyInputForm: null,
      thisValue: this.value
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
    <button v-if="!thisValue && !keyInputForm" @click="keyInputForm=true;thisValue=''">Добавить {{ name }}</button>
    <div>
      <h4 v-if="!keyInputForm" class="card-title" @click="keyInputForm = true">{{ value }}</h4>
      <input v-else type="text" :value="value" :name="name" v-model="thisValue" @input="$emit('input', thisValue)" @blur="keyInputForm = false;$emit('edit-field', $event)">
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dataObject: {
      name: 'Name',
      // surname: undefined,
      age: '17',
      id: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editField(e) {
      console.clear();
      const value = e.target.value;
      const key = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name');
      // axios.post(this.postURL, { user_id: this.dataObject.id, field_name: key, field_value: value })
      console.log('axios post => ', {
        user_id: this.dataObject.id,
        field_name: key,
        field_value: value
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input-form v-model="dataObject.name" name="name" @edit-field="editField"></input-form>
  <input-form v-model="dataObject.surname" name="surname" @edit-field="editField"></input-form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Можно v-for исключить ? У меня приходит объект, но мне из него к примеру не все данные нужно циклом выводить, а к примеру только age и name ...

Comment: дополнил ответ без `v-for`

Comment: У меня после нажатия enter должна обрабатывать функция значения этого поля v-on:keyup.enter="event => editField(event, 'age')

Comment: а что делает функция?

Comment: Добавил функцию в вопросе

Comment: Добавил функцию в ответе, по потере фокуса `input` происходит инициализация функции `editField`

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек, на высоте !

Comment: А как в компоненте проверить  если пустые данные dataObject.name то выводить <h4>Добавить</h4> ?

Comment: дополнил ответ, когда свойства нет или оно пустое будет кнопка `Добавить {{ name }}` выводится